# SICP with DrRacket

Tags: racket, sicp

Does anyone have experience with http://www.neilvandyke.org/racket-sicp in class? Is it mature enough?

Comment: Given the fact that it hasn't been updated in 3.5 years, I'd say it's about as mature as it'll get.. I've been using "vanilla" racket for SICP and I haven't had to do that much workaround.

Answer (score 5):

There is another version of the library on the new package server. I think it's based on Neil's version, but it does have more recent updates. You can find it by running:

```
raco pkg install sicp
```

Or in DrRacket by going to `File -> Install Package...` and typing in `sicp` into the box and hitting install.

Comment: This package is only the picture language developed in SICP (http://pkg-build.racket-lang.org/doc/sicp-manual/index.html). This is not the full support for SICP book.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently doing the last few questions of Chapter 2 and till date I have used Racket + Emacs(with racket-mode, because I could get it running quickly) for all the code. The only exception was the section "A picture language" -- for which I used the SICP package in order to save time.

If you have not started, I'd recommend you pick Dr. Racket for now. The introductory section of the book will anyhow get you up and running with Scheme, and if you do encounter any issues in the later chapters, then you'll have enough knowledge to fill the gap and create your own workarounds.